# unable to connect to epmd (port 4369) on node1: timeout (timed out) ubuntu 18.04

Tags: rabbitmq, cluster-computing

when I try to join - node to cluster:

sudo rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@node1
Error: unable to connect to nodes [rabbit@node1]: nodedown

## DIAGNOSTICS

attempted to contact: [rabbit@node1]

rabbit@node1:

- unable to connect to epmd (port 4369) on node1: timeout (timed out)

Comment: We have detailed guide line https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html this is a common problem when the node can't reach the other node for some reason

Comment: @GabrieleSantomaggio please provide more details in the answer other than just a link

Answer (score 0):

In case you still expect this error, How I solved mine is by going to the hosts.file and check first if "127.0.0.1" is there.. if so I commented mine out and entered it again like this "127.0.0.1 rabbitmq". After that save the changes on the file, restart the rabbitmq service and try again.. for me it worked.